# Is it possible to display items with different content types in a content query webpart

Tags: 2010, content-type, content-query-web-part, query

I am trying to configure a content query webpart to display three different content types from three different lists. Is this possible or can you only target a query to specify a single content type? I should specify that I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, did you tried the Content Search Webpart? It very easy to bring on multiple content types and from multiple lists.

Comment: I should have specified, that I am using SharePoint 2010 in this case, I don't believe 2010 has the content search webpart, which is why I am using a query.